# Unity: Will get a StackOverflowException if I try to get a singleton that is registered in multiple mappings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Given are the following two interfaces and one class:

```
interface IRepository<T> {}

interface IXRepository : IRepository<MyType> {}

class XRepository : IXRepository {}
```

I want to have a singleton of type  `XRepository` that can be resolved either by means of `IRepository<MyType>` or `IXRepository`.

I started with the following code:

```
public void Register<TFrom, TTo>(params Type[] typesToRegister) where TTo : TFrom
{
    parentContainer.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    foreach (Type type in typesToRegister)
    {
        parentContainer.RegisterType(type, typeof(TTo), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<TFrom>()));
    }
}
```

And here is the client method call:

```
service.Register<IRepository<MyType>, XRepository>(typeof(IXRepository));
```

The childContainer's registrations after executing this statement (headings: RegisteredType, MappedToType, Name and LifetimeManagerType):

- `typeof(IRepository<MyType>)`, `typeof(XRepository>)`, `null`, `typeof(HierarchicalLifetimeManager)`
- `typeof(IXRepository)`, `typeof(XRepository)`, `null`, `typeof(HierarchicalLifetimeManager)`

But if I try to resolve by means of `IRepository<MyType>` (or `IXRepository`), a StackOverflowException will be thrown. This is because the lambda expression in `new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<TFrom>())` is executed again and again.
Does anyone know what's going on under the hood? What is the reason for executing the lambda expression when requesting a `IRepository<MyType>`?

I found out that if you provide a name (**"gaga"** in this example) when registering, no StackOverflowException will be thrown:

- `typeof(IRepository<MyType>)`, `typeof(XRepository>)`, **`"gaga"`**, `typeof(HierarchicalLifetimeManager)`
- `typeof(IXRepository)`, `typeof(XRepository)`, `null`, `typeof(HierarchicalLifetimeManager)`

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the concrete type `XRepository` as a singleton, and then register both interfaces to be resolved with that type:

```
container.RegisterType<XRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IRepository<String>, XRepository>();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IXRepository), typeof(XRepository));
```

If you run the following code, you will see the singleton behaviour is applied and child containers are taken into account:

```
var isSingleton = container.Resolve<IRepository<String>>() == container.Resolve<IXRepository>();

var outerInstance = container.Resolve<IXRepository>();
using(var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer())
{
    isSingleton = childContainer.Resolve<IRepository<String>>() == childContainer.Resolve<IXRepository>();
    var isHierarchichalSingleton = outerInstance  != childContainer.Resolve<IXRepository>();
}
```

As a side note, your issue can be replicated in a more simpler way. <strike>This might be a bug in Unity</strike> This is as per design on Unity (check @Lukazoid comment and answer), For example:

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar { }
class Foo : IFoo, IBar  { }

container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
container.RegisterType<IBar, Foo>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IFoo>()));
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

Comment: This isn't a bug, when you specify injection members such as `InjectionFactory` these are used whenever creating the target type, regardless of the from type, the way to specify different injection members, lifetime managers etc is to use named registrations.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn´t really aware that injection members were applied by target type and not per registration. If a class implements 2 interfaces, and I apply an injection member to only one of the registrations, I wasn´t expecting it to be applied on both. So if `Foo` implements both `IFoo` and `IBar`, I wasnt expecting an injection member to the `IBar` registration to affect also the `IFoo` one!

Answer (score 0):

When using `LifetimeManagers` with Unity, only the last `LifetimeManager` specified for the target type is used. Multiple interface mappings to the same target type will all use the same `LifetimeManager`, e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<MyType>, XRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IXRepository, XRepository>();

var first = container.Resolve<IRepository<MyType>>();
var second = container.Resolve<IXRepository>();

Console.WriteLine("Same instance: {0}", ReferenceEquals(first, second));
```

Will output

> Same instance: True

Based on this fact, your register method can be changed like so:

```
public void Register<TFrom, TTo>(params Type[] typesToRegister) where TTo : TFrom
{
    parentContainer.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    foreach (Type type in typesToRegister)
    {
        parentContainer.RegisterType(type, typeof(TTo));
    }
}
```

Here is a LINQPad sample demonstrating the solution: http://share.linqpad.net/dbd9hx.linq